# External schema import not supported

Tags: wsdl

I want to import the external WSDL to SalesForce This is the wsdl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="FaxService" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://www.deferopro.com/FaxService/FaxService.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://www.deferopro.com/FaxService/FaxService.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://www.deferopro.com/FaxService/FaxService.svc?xsd=xsd2" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Technofax.WCF"/>
</xsd:schema>

</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="IFaxService_SendFax_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SendFax"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="IFaxService_SendFax_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SendFaxResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="IFaxService_GetFaxStatus_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetFaxStatus"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="IFaxService_GetFaxStatus_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetFaxStatusResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="IFaxService">
<wsdl:operation name="SendFax">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IFaxService/SendFax" message="tns:IFaxService_SendFax_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IFaxService/SendFaxResponse" message="tns:IFaxService_SendFax_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetFaxStatus">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IFaxService/GetFaxStatus" message="tns:IFaxService_GetFaxStatus_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IFaxService/GetFaxStatusResponse" message="tns:IFaxService_GetFaxStatus_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="serviceBasicHttpBinding" type="tns:IFaxService">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="SendFax">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IFaxService/SendFax" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetFaxStatus">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IFaxService/GetFaxStatus" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="FaxService">
<wsdl:port name="serviceBasicHttpBinding" binding="tns:serviceBasicHttpBinding">
<soap:address location="http://www.deferopro.com/FaxService/FaxService.svc"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

But I am getting " External schema import not supported" I tried some solution like remove the import tag and compy paste the content of that tag, but  no solution,

Can anyone give the solution properly with changes in above code ASAP   , It will be great help, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

WSDLs with external XSD references are not supported for import at this time.

You would need to flatten the WSDL to include the XSD types or handcraft the webservice classes.

I believe [XMLSpy](http://www.altova.com/xmlspy/wsdl-editor.html) helps with flattening the WSDL.